# Passing Props to grandchild React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-class-based-component

Child:

```
class Plus extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick(){
    console.log('It's Working!')
    this.props.handleButtonChange()
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <i
          className="fa fa-plus fa-2x"
          onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
        ></i>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Plus;
```

Parent:

```
class NoteCreation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="note-creation">
        <form action="">
          <Plus handleButtonChange={this.props.handleButtonChange} />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NoteCreation;
```

GrandParent Component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      buttonStat : false
    };
    this.handleButtonChange = this.handleButtonChange(this);

  }

  handleButtonChange(){
    this.setState({
      buttonStat : true
    })
  }


  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <NoteCreation
          handleButtonChange={this.handleButtonChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I simply want to pass the method handleButtonChange() from grandParent all the way to child (which is a button), as the button is clicked it triggers the click event which fires up this function making changes in grandparent component(i.e. setting button state)
where am i wrong at or this approach is completely wrong I am really new to react.
i am just want to set state in grandParent via child click event.
i keep getting this error `TypeError: this.props.handleButtonChange is not a function`
would appreciate any help

Comment: Shouldn't it be this.handleButtonChange = this.handleButtonChange.bind(this) in App component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your top component

It should be

```
this.handleButtonChange = this.handleButtonChange.bind(this);
```

and not

```
this.handleButtonChange = this.handleButtonChange(this);
```

Alternatively you can declare your method like this

```
  handleButtonChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      buttonStat : true
    })
  }
```

without using `bind` at all.

Answer (score 0):

In grandParent component, you should bind it to current component by keyword bind to pass it through props.
this.handleButtonChange = this.handleButtonChange.bind(this);